# Python - How to filter through a list of files and return only the values containing a certain extension?

Tags: python

Using python 3.7 , I need to take a list `example_list = ["example1.jar","example2.txt"`] of files like the one shown and create a function that returns only the name of the files ending in ".jar" Is there a short and concise way to get this done?

Comment: Please write down the code you have made. And explain in more detail the problems that you find from your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post some code and Add to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file names are strings in a list, you can use `list comprehension` with the function `endswith()`:

```
files_filtered = [x for x in example_list if x.endswith('.jar')]
```

This returns:

```
['example1.jar']
```

Answer (score 3):

Use list comprehensions:

```
[name for name in example_list if name.endswith(".jar")]
```

Comment: breaks if there is a file named `.jar`

Answer (score 2):

This may be overkill but you can use [`pathlib.PurePath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pure-paths) for this, which also provides functionality for if supplied full paths as well:

```
from pathlib import PurePath

example_list = ["example1.jar","example2.txt"]
paths = map(PurePath, example_list)

names = [p.name for p in paths if p.suffix == '.jar']
```

Results:

```
>>> names
['example1.jar']
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do this:

```
list(filter(lambda item: item.endswith('.jar'), ["example1.jar","example2.txt", "example3.jar"])
```

Note: this implementation will be slower then using list comprehension because of some overhead in function calls.

Answer (score 0):

create a function and use `split` method and list comprehension

```
def filter_files(files_list: list) -> list:
    return [file for file in files_list if file.split('.')[1] == 'jar']

print(filter_files(["example1.jar","example2.txt"]))
>>> ['example1.jar']
```